# Upper Division Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I am taking an upper division undergraduate linear algebra course, and I just need help understanding my reading, which states:

"Let S be a nonempty set and F be any field, and let F(S,F) denote the set of all functions from S to F. Two functions f and g in F(S,F) are called equal if f(s)=g(s) for each s, an element of S."

Basically, these 2 sentences make no sense to me, and I would greatly appreciate it if someone can break this down for me.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question.

Comment: Right community is : [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the sentence "equal if f(s)=g(s) for each s, an element of S."  s mean all of the element S 
 so, In all case s, if f(s) and g(s) equal, function f=g